# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

While setting an environment for tensorflow models, when I run `python model_builder_test.py` at last step, causes `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32'`, does someone know how to fix it? Thanks.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

```
PS C:\Users\User\models\research\object_detection\builders> python model_builder_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\User\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 17, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
  File "C:\Users\User\models\research\object_detection\builders\anchor_generator_builder.py", line 18, in <module>
    from object_detection.anchor_generators import grid_anchor_generator
  File "C:\Users\User\models\research\object_detection\anchor_generators\grid_anchor_generator.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import ops
  File "C:\Users\User\models\research\object_detection\utils\ops.py", line 282, in <module>
    dtype=tf.float32):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32'
```

Comment: What did you use to install tensorflow?

Comment: I had the same problem when I first installed `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`. Then uninstalled `tensorflow-gpu`. `tensorflow` remained but uninstall process must have messed it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tensorflow has float32.

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: tf.float32
Out[2]: tf.float32
```

Above is my output confirming that. This is a known problem while installing in windows.You can take a look [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7285).

To fix it, you just need to reinstall `tensorflow` using the following commang

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
```

Note:One More common mistake is naming a module as `tensorflow`. this might make it to import this module you created which is empty

Comment: raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

Comment: Hey, this means that you are not able to connect to internet or pypi is blocked. Try manually downloading and installing via python setup.py install command

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the command:
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow