# How to install tensorflow without pip in the right way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, error-handling, pip

So I have installed tensorflow with pip using `pip install tensorflow==1.15` a few days ago, today I wanted to search for my models-master file and I didn't find it. I uninstalled tensorflow using `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then I installed it from the [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) and added it to the folder of the project I am working on like, it is in the same folder as the .py files of my original project. This is because I need to use protoc on the files because I got error messages before. I think I got the protoc part down now but I can't test it, because whenever I want to run my main file, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\captcha solver\main_.py", line 1, in <module>
    from CAPTCHA_object_detection import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\captcha solver\CAPTCHA_object_detection.py", line 18, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\ops.py", line 291, in <module>
    dtype=tf.float32):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'float32'
```

I think this is because of the way I installed tensorflow, but I don't know what I did wrong, I have never installed modules without pip though.

Comment: Installing Tensorflow from source is a tedious process by building the extensions with Bazel, see [Build from source on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). Which boils down to building a local wheel and installing it, one way or another. What steps did you follow when installing from source repository?

Comment: maybe you created file `tensorflow.py` and now it uses your file `tensorflow` and it can't find `float32` in your `tensorflow.py` ?

Comment: well I installed tensorflow from the linked github. I then used cd in the command prompt to get into the tensorflow research folder. I then used the command "protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=." I guess that wasn't all I had to do even though I thought so

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654346/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-float32.